Is it a good idea to append json+ld file into the body using javascript
I'm trying to add structured data to my product page on Shopify in a json+ld file
But when it comes to the reviews, I'm using stamped.io and to get all reviews array I needed to fetch data from their stamped API and here's how I did it
<script>
 let url = "https://stamped.io/api/widget/reviews?sId={{storeHash}}&apiKey={{apiKeyPublic}}&productId={{product.id}}"

 fetch(URL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      console.log(result.data)
   })
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
</script>

Now I need to use this result.data inside JSON-LD script, but since JavaScript works on the client side and liquid works on the server side I cannot assign the value inside a liquid variable. Basically, I can't do this
{% assign data = result.data %}

I found the only way for it to work is to create a javascript variable with the json-ld object inside of it and then append it to the body using the appendChild() function. Like this:
fetch('https://api.stamped.io/v2/...') 
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
const reviews = result.data;

const jsonLd = {
  ...props,
  "review": reviews.map(review => ({
    "@type": "Review",
    "author": review.author,
    "datePublished": review.date,
    "reviewBody": review.text,
    "reviewRating": {
      "@type": "Rating",
      "ratingValue": review.rating
    }
  }))
};


const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.type = 'application/ld+json';
scriptTag.text = JSON.stringify(jsonLd);
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
})

What I'm worried about is Google missing this structured data if it doesn't load fast or potentially if Google does not index it
Ideally, what's the best way to handle this issue?

Googlebot for search renders the page so it can pick up that structured data. If it takes a long time to load, then Googlebot may not wait long enough for it. The best way to know is to check if the reviews are picked up in the Google Search Console.
